# A proposition about minimal Stinespring dilation in C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

**Proposition 1.** Let $(\pi, \widehat{H}, V)$ be the minimal Stinespring dilation of a contractive completely positive map $\phi: A \rightarrow B$. Then, there exists a *-homomorphism 
$$\rho: \phi(A)^{'} \rightarrow \pi(A)^{'}\subset B(\widehat{H})$$
(the $\phi(A)^{'}$ denotes the commutant of $\phi(A)^{'}$)  such that
$$\phi(a)x=V^{\ast}\pi(a)\rho(x)V$$
for every $a\in A$ and $x\in \phi(A)^{'}$.

*Proof.* For $x\in \phi(A)^{'}$, we define a linear operator $\rho(x)$ on the span of $\pi(A)VH$ by
$$\rho(x)(\sum_{i}\pi(a_{i})V\xi_{i})=\sum_{i}\pi(a_{i})Vx\xi_{i}.$$
Once we prove that $\rho(x)$ is well-defined and bounded for every $x\in \phi(A)^{'}$, **it is not hard to check that $\rho$ gives rise to a $*$-representation of $\phi(A)^{'}$ on $\widehat{H}$ such that $\rho(\phi(A)^{'}) \subset\pi(A)^{'}$ and $\rho(a)x=V^{*}\pi(a)\rho(x)V$ for every $a\in A$ and $x\in \rho(A)^{'}$.**  ...................

I have two question about the quotation above:

1. How to explain $\rho$ is a ***-representation** of $\phi(A)^{'}$?
2. How to compute the equation $\rho(a)x=V^{*}\pi(a)\rho(x)V$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. We have
   $$
   \rho(x)\rho(y)\pi(a)V\xi=\rho(x)\pi(a)Vy\xi=\pi(a)Vxy\xi=\rho(xy)\pi(a)V\xi,
   $$
   so $\rho(xy)=\rho(x)\rho(y)$. The computation for linearity is similar. And 
   $$
   \langle \rho(x)^*\pi(a)V\xi,\pi(b)V\eta\rangle=\langle \pi(a)V\xi,\rho(x)\pi(b)V\eta\rangle
   =\langle \pi(a)V\xi,\pi(b)Vx\eta\rangle=\langle V^*\pi(b)^*\pi(a)V\xi,x\eta\rangle=\langle\phi(b^*a)\xi,x\eta\rangle=\langle x^*\phi(b^*a)\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle \phi(b^*a)x^*\xi,\eta\rangle
   =\langle V\pi(b)^*\pi(a)Vx^*\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle \pi(a)Vx^*\xi,\pi(b)V\eta\rangle=\langle \rho(x^*)\pi(a)V\xi,\pi(b)V\eta\rangle,
   $$
   so $\rho(x^*)=\rho(x)^*$. All this works because, being well-defined and bounded, we can extend $\rho(x)$ to all of $\widehat H$.
2. For $\xi\in H$,
   $$
   \phi(a)x\xi=V^*\pi(a)Vx\xi=V^*\rho(x)\pi(a)V\xi=V^*\pi(a)\rho(x)V\xi.
   $$

Comment: @Maritin Argerami Thanks, Martin.

Comment: Martin, can you please explain the relevance of the requirement "contractive completely positive", instead of just "completely positive"?

Comment: I don't think it's relevant. Since cp implies cb, one can always divide by the cb norm, do the proposition (1.5.6 in Brown-Ozawa) and then multiply by the cb norm again, putting the weight on $V$ and $V^*$.